# Stopping the sound at mouse click in Actionscript 3

Tags: audio, actionscript

So I have this code, I want the sound to stop when I click on the start button but when I click on the start button the sound doesn't stop but it's volume is decreased, it's very odd. Can someone fix this ?

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(new URLRequest("Sounds/Sound.mp3"));
var channel:SoundChannel = mySound.play();

channel = mySound.play();



StartButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, StartGame);


function StartGame(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    channel.stop();
    gotoAndPlay(2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already initialized channel in the line

```
var channel:SoundChannel = mySound.play();
```

Then, you (probably accidentally) gave it a value anew:

```
channel = mySound.play();
```

You'll find if you take that last line out, the code will work just fine.